# Function "pop" is returning an error. I am trying to remove an element within the list

Tags: python, function

I am trying to remove the 4th element in a list using the pop function. However, I kept getting an error message back. Please help.

```
inventory = ["twin bed", "twin bed", "headboard", "queen bed", "king bed", "dresser",
             "dresser", "table", "table", "nightstand", "nightstand", "king bed",
             "king bed", "twin bed", "twin bed", "sheets", "sheets", "pillow",
             "pillow"]

removed_item = inventory.pop[4]
print(removed_item)
```

This is the error message that keeps being returned;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 18, in <module>
    removed_item = inventory.pop[4]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Did you mean: ‘inventory.pop(4)’?

Comment: **Functions** always require any arguments passed to them to be in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right `pop()` does take a index, but you dont write it like `pop[4]` therefore just like quamrana said, you should put `inventory.pop(4)` instead of `inventory.pop[4]`